# Picasso library to load images from Parse.com Using A RecyclerView gives Error "Target must not be null"

Tags: android, parse-platform, picasso, android-recyclerview

I have three images stored on Parse.com in a table class called "events" in a table column named "image"

I haven't found a way to load all the images from Parse.com in a recyclerview without only ONE image being displayed so i resorted to Picasso Image loader to see if i could display all three images inside the RecyclerView at once(without a single image being  displayed only)

But my dilemma now is that i am getting this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
        at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
        at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
        at pi.com.myparserecyclercardview.MainActivity$1.done(MainActivity.java:260)
        at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:45)
        at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:1)
        at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

It shows line:260 in my main activity which has:

```
  .into(imageViewPicasso);
```

THIS IS MY MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



//Defining Variables
protected Toolbar toolbar;
protected NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
protected Button mButtonHeader;
protected TextView mDayOfTheWeek;
protected TextView mDate;


private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

//New Variables
private CustomAdapter mAdapter;





final List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //RecyclerView with Parse
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_layout);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data);



    //Query to load String data into the card view/recycler view
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("events");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                    Information information = new Information();

                    information.mNewstTitle = objects.get(i).getString("name");
                    information.mNewsStory = objects.get(i).getString("shortinfo");
                    //information.partyCost = parseObject.getString("partyName");


                    String url=objects.get(i).getParseFile("image").getUrl();


                    //information.mEventsPhotoID = objects.getParseFile("partyFlyerImage");
                    //information.mEventsPhotoID = objects.get(i).getParseFile("image");




                    //information.mNewsPhotoIcon = R.drawable.newsitem));

                    //Initialize ImageView
                    ParseImageView imageViewPicasso = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.eventsPhotoID);

                    //Loading image from below url into imageView
                    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                            .load(url)
                            .into(imageViewPicasso);



                    data.add(information);
                }
            } else {
                // something went wrong
            }
            //adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(startPosition, imageUrls.length);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    });










}//END onCreate



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

 }//END MAIN ACTVITY CLASS
```

THIS IS MY ADAPTER CLASS:

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends     RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
//private List<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

/*public CustomAdapter (Context context,List<Information>data){
    this.context=context;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data= data;
}*/

public CustomAdapter (Context context,List<Information>data){
    this.context=context;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data= data;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_upcomingshows, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);


    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){
    Information current= data.get(position);
    //holder.mEventsPhotoID.setImageResource(current.mEventsPhotoID);
    holder.mNewstTitle.setText(current.mNewstTitle);
    holder.mNewsStory.setText(current.mNewsStory);
    holder.mEventsPhotoID.setParseFile(current.mEventsPhotoID);
    //holder.mEventsPhotoIDTwo.setParseFile(current.mEventsPhotoIDTwo);



}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){

    return data.size();
}


class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    //ImageView mEventsPhotoID;
    TextView mNewstTitle;
    TextView mNewsStory;
    ParseImageView mEventsPhotoID;
    //ParseImageView mEventsPhotoIDTwo;



    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);



        //promoterImage = (ParseImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.promoterPicImage);
        mEventsPhotoID = (ParseImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventsPhotoID);
        //mEventsPhotoIDTwo = (ParseImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventsPhotoIDTwo);
        mNewstTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsTitle);
        mNewsStory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsStory);


        mNewstTitle.setOnClickListener(this);
        mNewsStory.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Recycle Click" + getLayoutPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(getLayoutPosition()==0){
            Intent intentEventsWebView = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), EventsWebViewActivity.class);
            //intentIndependenceDay.putExtra("MyClass", myclass);
            intentEventsWebView.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            itemView.getContext().startActivity(intentEventsWebView);
        }
        if(getLayoutPosition()==1){
            Intent intentIndependenceDay = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), NextActivity.class);
            //intentIndependenceDay.putExtra("MyClass", myclass);
            intentIndependenceDay.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            itemView.getContext().startActivity(intentIndependenceDay);
        }
        if(getLayoutPosition()==2){
            Intent intentShelleyMaxwellDance = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), OtherActivity.class);
            //intentIndependenceDay.putExtra("MyClass", myclass);
                   intentShelleyMaxwellDance.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            itemView.getContext().startActivity(intentShelleyMaxwellDance);
        }


    }
}
 }
```

Comment: I believe it means your `imageViewPicasso` is null. Can you check if it isn't null?

Comment: Target is the URL from which the image will load , before calling Picasso's load method, you must have a check, if (path ! =null). also please check the view , it also must not be null, Picasso, has not handled null path exceptions, so the app will crash if path will be empty or null

Comment: okay, how do i check the view to see if it is null?

Comment: i even tried to do this in my onBindViewHolder

Comment: Picasso.with(context).load("http://files.parsetfss.com/a6ad4195-364f-4e68-a851-57d48425b5a7/tfss-3549b3fa-f466-4739-93df-a32d000ee5e1-tumblr_nsg74e2TWy1tkhysoo1_1280.jpg").into(holder.mEventsPhotoID);

Answer (score 0):

I have spent my whole day to resolve this. parseFile.getURL() return local URL of parse server which we can not access using picasso. instead it replace local URL with your parse URL as below

parseFile.getURL() return url in below format which is own parse server local URL.

http://localhost:1337/parse/files/ObQCLvddfasAzP7LWcZYPmzMYIDEALOGRPAAHTO/f2823c0b613248sdafsa60bdfc941c230ba_profile.png

use below code to load image using picasso

String [] imgArr= parseFile.getUrl().split("parse/");
                    Picasso.with(ImageDemo.this).load(NetworkConstants.PARSE_URL+imgArr[1]).into(imageView);

this is 100% working code